# How many ml to fill a hole?

Tags: geometry

I have a 44mm hole 5ft deep. I am putting a 38mm rod into the hole. How many ml of epoxy do I need to put into the hole to fill it to the 5ft once the rod is inserted?

Comment: Is this real life scenario or a homework problem?

Comment: Why does this have commutative algebra tag?

Answer (score 0):

The hole and rod are both cylinders. Compute the volumes using $V=\pi r^2 h$. Subtract. Do you know how many mm in a foot and how many mm$^3$ in a ml?

The hole has $r=22$ mm, $h=5\cdot 304.8=1524$ mm, $V \approx 2.32\cdot 10^6 \text{mm}^3$
The rod has  $r=19$ mm, $h=5\cdot 304.8=1524$ mm, $V \approx 1.73\cdot 10^6 \text{mm}^3$
The empty space is about $6\cdot 10^5 \text{mm}^3=600 $ml
This is very sensitive to whether the hole is exactly a cylinder as specified.  When I drill concrete the hole is rather irregular and often larger than the drill bit says.

Comment: Note: in real life, the amount of Epoxy would be a bit less, due to soil interference.

Comment: This is a real life problem and it's for my 78 year old grandfather at work.

Comment: They are drilling into concrete not soil.